# blur.js trying to request "none" and div not expanding 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use the http://blurjs.com/ to blur our the header bar's BG of the header image. However it gives me a interesting error I can't seem to track down. It may be something to do with the main code, and compatibility, but I'm not sure.

http://jordan.rave5.com/tmp/

Error is

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)      http://jordan.rave5.com/tmp/none

Also the background-gradient div is having trouble expanding 100% when the page is first initialing loading when the content box is small. I've tried adding a another div within it at 100% or bigger to push it out, but it just ends up pushing the footer further down when the content area expands. Kinda annoying.

Comment: This error message is actually pretty common. I've often had network requests fail in my console and wondered, what on earth is trying to get that weird url, `localhost/test/undefined`. Of course the solution will be different in each case :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code fails at line 285 of blurjs.js. This is because blurjs is looking for a css property on the element you pass in as the `source` (line 202). You are setting up `.header-img` (an image element) as the source option and so blurjs can't find a `background-image` property on it hence the default value of the css property is returned, `none` and so you get the error when you try to load an image with that value. Change blurjs.js at line 202:

```
var formattedSource;
if($source.is('img'))
    formattedSource = $source.attr('src');
else
    formattedSource = ($source.css('backgroundImage')).replace(/"/g, "").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks, yeah someone else pointed that out to me and I was trying to rewrite everything to handle a background image (which would make a slider a lot harder) I hope this works. :)

Edit: Works like a charm.

Comment: Well you would choose background-image if you wanted tiling and such but you can't resize the source image itself, only the container it is in. With images themselves you have the ability to shrink or expand the picture itself.

Comment: I should have qualified my statements to be accurate for CSS 2.1, for CSS 3 `background-size` take a look on the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) website.

Comment: Oh that is nice, I didn't see the background-size when looking over CSS3. However it still makes a simple slider a bit of a annoyance changing the background image and sizes.