# Use blur.js on a Google map (v3 API)

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently what I am attempting to do, is to use blur.js on a div named `map_canvas` which contains a google map. I've already tried to create a div over it and simply use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#blurredCoverDiv').blurjs({
        source: '#map_canvas',
        radius: 30,
        overlay: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)'
    });

});
```

However, that is resulting in an error in the console:

```
GET http://[site]/none 404 (Not Found) blur.js:279
```

I've seen one stackoverflow question involving [this very question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231040/blur-js-trying-to-request-none-and-div-not-expanding-100), however, the solution there didn't seem to solve my problem.

Any ideas as to why this may be happening, or a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You get 404 error because blur.js is looking for a `background-image` in the `source`'s div. Since your `map_canvas` is set to `none`, blur.js will push a 404 error to the console (*'none' is not found*).

I haven't tested it, but the solution comes to my mind right now is to set a [google map static image](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/) as your `map_canvas`'s `background-image`. If that works, you can go on and write a function which takes the current view on the `map_canvas`'s canvas and apply it as a static image to its `background-image`. Let me know if it's working.

Comment: Good suggestion, unfortunately I couldn't get it to work and ended up completely leaving the idea.

Comment: btw, have you tried using CSS3 filters instead? http://davidwalsh.name/css-filters

Comment: Yep, I spent a couple of hours trying to find some way to use filters on the map in order to blur it, and it would be fairly easy, however I only want to blur a portion of the map, which unfortunately increases the difficulty of implementing it exponentially.

Comment: A blurred white-background div with low opacity on top of the map wouldn't do the job?

Answer (score 0):

You can use html2canvas from this link http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

It lets you take screenshot from the div. Here is a example:

```
html2canvas($map,{
                useCORS:true,
                height:null,
                width:null,
                onrendered: function(canvas){
                    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    $('.blurred-bg').css("background-image","url('"+dataUrl+"')");
                }
            });
```

The value 'null' for height and width is used to capture the map in the full size of the div.
Here is the result: [Example blur div over maps v3](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-l29yOnOYJjg/VHnFj3MgHfI/AAAAAAAAF9I/yewPG5dH09I/w1127-h614-no/Untitled%2Bpicture.png)

Comment: would be better if you would link a functional example, instead of a image.